# window.onbeforeunload function stops triggering randomly

Tags: javascript, asp.net, onbeforeunload

I'm working on a asp.net project in which I have a function defined for the onbeforeunloead event.

It worked just fine in the tests, but when in production seems to be failing randomly for some reason I can't debug.

Any insights will be helpfull.

Thank's in advance.

onbeforeunload script

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    var sinCasos = false;
    var error = false;
    var malPcrc = false;
    var banderaConfirmaCierra = false;
    if ($("#alertaSinCasos").is(':visible')) { sinCasos = true }
    if ($("#alertaError").is(':visible')) { error = true }
    if ($("#alertaOrgErronea").is(':visible')) { malPcrc = true }
    if ($("#banderaConfirmaCierra").is(':visible')) { banderaConfirmaCierra = true }
    if ((warnBeforeClose) && !(sinCasos || error || malPcrc || banderaConfirmaCierra)) {
        //ajax
        abandonaCaso();
        console.log('sin casos: ' + sinCasos);
        console.log(!(sinCasos || error || malPcrc || banderaConfirmaCierra));
        console.log('warn: ' + warnBeforeClose);
        return "Los cambios podrían no guardarse, desea continuar?";
    }
}
```

Comment: Modern Browsers behavior. Sometime considering this method as unsafe ?